# How can we change the filename of spark output [sparkJava]

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to change spark output filename , is the anyway to do that, Spark is writting in AWS S3.

Comment: This is too short description. provide more details, and if possible, a code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Check below code will work for `HDFS` & also `S3`.

Created `rename` function which will take path & name to be changed, if `directory` contains multiple files, This will just append `sequence` number at the end of file name like `json_data_1.json`

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path, RemoteIterator}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

// For converting to scala Iterator
implicit def convertToScalaIterator[T](remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]): Iterator[T] = {
    case class wrapper(remoteIterator: RemoteIterator[T]) extends Iterator[T] {
      override def hasNext: Boolean = remoteIterator.hasNext
      override def next(): T = remoteIterator.next()
    }
    wrapper(remoteIterator)
}
```

```
import java.net.URI
def fs(path: String) = FileSystem.get(URI.create(path),spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

// Rename files 
def rename(path: String,name: String) = {
    fs(path)
    .listFiles(new Path(path),true)
    .toList
    .filter(_.isFile)
    .map(_.getPath)
    .filterNot(_.toString.contains("_SUCCESS"))
    .zipWithIndex
    .map(p => fs(p._1.toString).rename(p._1,new Path(s"${p._1.getParent}/${name}_${p._2}.${p._1.toString.split("\\.")(1)}")))
}
```

```
scala> val path = "/tmp/samplea"
path: String = /tmp/samplea

scala> df.repartition(5).write.format("json").mode("overwrite").save(path)

scala> s"ls -ltr ${path}".!
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel    0 Jun  6 13:57 part-00000-607ffd5e-7d28-4331-9a69-de36254c80b1-c000.json
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel  282 Jun  6 13:57 part-00001-607ffd5e-7d28-4331-9a69-de36254c80b1-c000.json
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel    0 Jun  6 13:57 _SUCCESS

scala> rename(path,"json_data")
res193: List[Boolean] = List(true, true)

scala> s"ls -ltr ${path}".!
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel    0 Jun  6 13:57 json_data_0.json
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel  282 Jun  6 13:57 json_data_1.json
-rw-r--r--  1 sriniva  wheel    0 Jun  6 13:57 _SUCCESS
```